# Error while installing Oracle 11g on Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, installation, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install Oracle 11g R2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit using the "silent" installer. I am using .rsp file with the process but getting this error:

```
[WARNING] [INS-06101] IP address of localhost could not be determined
   CAUSE: The localhost is not mapped to a valid IP address in Hosts file (Eg. /etc/hosts in Unix).
   ACTION: Assign a valid IP address for the localhost or set it to loopback IP address (127.0.0.1 in IPv4 or ::1 in IPv6).
   SUMMARY:
       - ip-172-30-0-89: ip-172-30-0-89
P.S. I still don't have a domain name for the server.
```

Thanks

Comment: Error is pretty clear

Comment: Can you suggest a solution? I googled it without a clear solution (as I mentioned, I still don't have a domain name for the server)

Comment: Try making an entry in your hosts file as `127.0.0.1 localhost`, and then try to install.